# Python Adding password to modify feature

Tags: python, excel, password-protection

I wanted to know if there was a way in python to enable a read only mode unless a password is specified. I can do it manually on excel through file -> save as -> tools -> general options, but I want to know if it is possible through python as well as I am trying to automate the process in my script

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`openpyxl` should have this capability, however being auto-generated, the easiest way to find out how to do it will be to create an empty excel workbook with the desired features, and search for how they were implemented in the xml structure. I did a very quick test to be able to find the [`openpyxl.workbook.protection`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.protection.html) module, but you will likely also need worksheet protection, and often generating the correct datatypes for the constructors can be tricky. This may be easier to do via file permissions with the OS if that's an option. Alternately, you might be able to export to something like a PDF which has plenty of security options with adobe.

Comment: I can certainly do it through the OS if that will make it possible. PDF will not be possible due to the structure of my excel file.